# CSS Positioning in Dreamweaver

Tags: css

Frustrated that I still can't grasp certain CSS concepts but anyway, here's the problem:

I want to center a LINE of TEXT at the bottom of my site (basic index.html splash page). I also want the text to float 10-20 pixels at the footer based on various monitor resolution so that it's always at the bottom.

What options do I need to tick off within the "Positioning" Style Sheet Properties? Relative? Fixed? Absolute?

So far my settings are "Relative" with 600px at the Top, and 200px at the Bottom. But it looks great on a 13" monitor and it goes right in the middle of the page on a 27" monitor, for example.

Just want to center the damn thing at the bottom with a little breathing space before the status bar in a browse - independent of monitor size.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed` to stick the footer to the bottom of the window. I've drawn up a quick demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EeTHg/).

The CSS:

```
div#footer {
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}​
```

The red background can obviously be removed, and the `padding-bottom` can be changed to your requirements.

The `bottom: 0`, `left: 0` and `right: 0` properties force the footer to the bottom of the page, and stretch it all the way across.

---

To make a a footer that *doesn't* stretch all the way across, try [this JSFiddle out instead](http://jsfiddle.net/XfPR4/1/). It uses an inner element and automatic left and right margins.

Comment: +1, may want to set explicit height and add that as padding/margin to the bottom of the [body] so the footer would not overlap important content

Comment: @o.v. Thank you for that - a good tip. I'll leave it in the comments so as to not duplicate information.